# The following themes are installed but incomplete

Tags: wordpress-theming

I have installed Woodmart theme through cpanel both parent and child theme.But after installing wordpress shows that

> The following themes are installed but incomplete-assets  Stylesheet is missing.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hglP.png)Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

just deactivate & delete woodmart child theme & active Woodmart Main Theme

Answer (score 0):

/*
Theme Name:   crocodile-commerce Child
Theme URI:    https://crocodile-commerce.com/
Description:  crocodile-commerce Child Theme
Author:
Author URI:   https://crocodile-commerce/
Template:     crocodile-commerce
Version:      1.0.0
License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
Text Domain:  crocodile-commerce-child
*/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).